# Sending email from Azure using on-prem SMTP server

Tags: c#, azure, email, smtp

We can't host SMTP server on Azure VM. Recommended way is to use third-party email services like SendGrid.

Can we use existing on-prem SMTP server to send email from Azure cloud? 
Will there be any specific settings need to be done on on-prem server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few of options depending on your architecture.

1. Create a VPN to your on premises network, route your SMTP traffic across the VPN.
2. Use your SMTP product's existing web service API and expose an endpoint to the Azure service. The Azure service then calls the web service to send the email.
3. If your on premise SMTP does not have an API, then write a web service, callable from Azure or exposed as a relay service.

If you update your question with answers to the below you will get more specific options.

- What services in Azure do you want to send from?
- What technology is your on-prem SMTP server?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid fiddling around with site to site VPN, you could try [**Azure Relay Hybrid Connections**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-relay/relay-hybrid-connections-dotnet-get-started). You do have to write a bit of code - or more like, bytes :) - but it's really nothing scary.

```
Client (VM in Azure) <---> Azure Relay endpoint <---> Server (SMTP server on-prem)
```

OR

As an even simpler approach - just use a [**Storage Queue**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-queues) and write a simple consumer (maybe a .NET or Node.js headless application) to process the messages on-prem.

[image: Competing Consumers Pattern]

Comment: I might not have liberty to install a consumer app on-prem. And I see both above approaches require to do so.

Comment: Then you'll pretty much have to expose your SMTP port to the Internet, that or Site-to-site VPN. I don't really see a 3rd option. If you ask me, I would definitely go for SendGrid, it has a very elegant API and needs no fussing around with tunnels.